# Add multiple Byte[] to one array in Java

Tags: java, android

I am having issues trying to add multiple byte arrays to one. I am not talking about concatenating here. I need to add individual items of the Byte[]. This is what i am looking for.

```
    byte[] one = [4,5,6];
    byte[] two = [1,2,1];
```

The result should be

```
    byte[] sum = [5,7,7];
```

This is just a simple example. I am writing my own algorithm to mix different pcm recordings in android. This is where i am stuck at. any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is my code snippet:

```
while(stream[1].read()!=-1) {   
List<byte[]> arrayColl = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
for(int i =0; i<recfiles.length; i++) {
stream[i].read(buffer);
arrayColl.add(buffer);
}
}
```

There can be multiple stream based on users selection. The loop above will read multiple streams in a buffer and that buffer is added to an ArrayList. Now what i need to do is to mix the bytes in the arraylist in a way i mentioned above.  The `buffer` is a `byte[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a simple [matrix addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition). You can accomplish this with a `for` loop by iterating over the domain of the loop's subscript operator (namely, from `0` to the length of the array) as follows:

```
int length = Math.min(one.length, two.length);
byte[] sum = new byte[length];
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    sum[i] = one[i] + two[i];
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to ensure that the two arrays are of the same size, you could use:

```
if (one.length != two.length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("unequal lengths");
}
int length = one.length; // or two.length
byte[] sum = new byte[length];
for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    sum[i] = one[i] + two[i];
}
```

Comment: Hi WChargin, thanks for the quick response. Seems like this is exactly right. I need one more suggestion. The algorithm i am working on mixes multiple files depending on the users selection. How can we tweak this to work with multiple byte[] not just two.

Comment: What do you mean to work with multiple `byte[]`s? Could you give an example?

Comment: Hi WChargin, I have added a code snippet which will give you the picture of what i am tring to do.

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple byte arrays, you need to loop through each one, adding the result to an accumulator array:

```
public byte[] sum(byte[]... arrays) {
    // optional: check that arrays.length > 0 (at least one array was passed)
    final int len = arrays[0].length;
    final byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (byte[] array : arrays) {
        // optional: test that array has length len
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            result[i] += array[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ted! With these two answers. I should be able to solve my issue.